# .htaccess redirect files with certain paths to another directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This might seem a bit basic and something that's been asked quite a lot around here, but I have a small .htaccess problem (mod_rewrite).

I'm working on a MVC framework for PHP (like everybody else...) and all traffic goes through index.php which then routes to the required controller and method. All that goes well. The structure is roughly something like this:

- application

  1. controllers
  2. models
  3. views
- cache
- framework
- public

  1. assets
  2. img
  3. css
  4. js
- index.php
- .htaccess

For an URL like myapp.com/css/ I need o load the CSS controller, index function. But for URLs like myapp.com/css/style.css I need to fetch the file from the public/css/directory

I'd hate writing /public/ for each file I want to include, so basically I need to redirect all traffic to /public/ if it's an actual file and keep the normal rewriting rule for all other URLs. I'm planning to use this in production and it would be much easier to let frontend developers do their stuff the way they normally do it and then just copy paste stuff into place instread of going through CSS to modify paths and such.

I came up with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(img|css|js|assets)/(.*).([a-z]{3})$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it has some obvious flaws. I don't mind having to set directories in the first regex, but checking that the path is a file the way I do seems rather unreliable. Using RewriteCond to check that it's a file didn't work for some reason and I think this method can fail for URLs like myapp.com/img/this-is-actually-an-article.aaa Of course, extensiuons can also be longer than 3 characters and I need to check that that's safe as well.

What's the best way to go about this? How do you guys ussually do it? Or is this a wrong approach from the very begining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-f` isn't working because the requested file is `/css/style.css` whereas the file on disk is `/public/css/style.css`.

I see no problem with declaring some predefined namespaces that you can't use in your application (like img, css, js, assets).

Eventually I think you will move to a situation where plugins for your framework can no longer decide where their resources are, the framework should decide it for them and possibly even load it for them. This resolves all your current issues as no plugin code will ever need to know anything about URLs. Regardless of your rewriting strategy I think this is something to aspire to.

Comment: Thanks for the -f tip, now it makes much more sense. At the moment I do have a CSS and a JS controller that generate minified&gzipped files to be used by the app at myapp.com/css/ and myapp.com/js/ Are you suggesting to blacklist all controllers that would have names that match names of the folders in /public/ as to avoid any possible conflict? That's a solution as well, I think, that would clear any confusion regarding where the resources should be loaded from.

Comment: Either you implement a blocklist or you put your entire application in it's own namespace. It doesn't really matter what you pick, so long as you don't get ambiguous URLs.

Comment: I see. Could you please explain the namespace approach a bit? Are you talking about "namespace dummy" or? How would that affect URLs?

Comment: Also, if I handle resources within my main() function logic from index.php and return the resources through PHP, would that be a performance hit? (using file_get_contents() and setting the appropiate headers) Or maybe having a Public controller to do that?

Comment: The word namespace is perhaps a bit confusing. More like 'folder'. Like 'css'. So you'd get: `site.com/app/fontpage` instead of `site.com/frontpage`. If you always have the `app` part there you can't accidentally overwrite an image resource.

Comment: I see what you mean, I thought you meant namespace as the keyword in PHP. Any ideas on performance issues if I'm passing the resources through PHP rather than redirecting to the resource?

Comment: Yea, you might get memory issues on really large files and you'll have to supply the right content-type headers for each static file type.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out for me. The htaccess solution and blocking controllers seems to work. Still have problems with .woff font files but will work that out. Cheers!